# "The public struct contains one or more non-public fields that will be exported" - but there are no fields?

Tags: c#, com-interop, tlbexp

I have the struct below which is being compiled for COM interop. I get the following build warning:

> warning : Type library exporter warning processing
>   'MyNamespace.MyStruct.k__BackingField,
>   MyAssemblyName'. **Warning: The public struct contains one
>   or more non-public fields that will be exported**.

But I don't see what it is referring to - *there are no non-public fields nor fields at all*. Maybe the compiler is generating something I can't see? What does this warning mean, and what if anything can I do to clean it up?

Here's the (slightly sanitized) code which is being built:

```
[Guid("....")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    public string StringA { get; set; }
    public string StringB { get; set; }

    public MyStruct(string a, string b)
    {
        StringA = a;
        StringB = b;
    }

    public MyStruct(MyStruct other)
    {
        StringA = other.StringA;
        StringB = other.StringB;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is MyStruct)) return false;
        var other = (MyStruct)obj;
        return
            other.StringA == this.StringA &&
            other.StringB == this.StringB;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyStructa, MyStructb) => a != null && a.Equals(b);
    public static bool operator !=(MyStructa, MyStructb) => !(a == b);
    public override int GetHashCode() => ToString().GetHashCode();

    public override string ToString() => $"{StringA}-{StringB}";
}
```

and for good measure here is the IDL that gets generated:

```
typedef [uuid(....), version(1.0), custom(xxxx, MyNamespace.MyStruct)]
struct tagMyStruct {
    LPSTR <StringA>k__BackingField;
    LPSTR <StringB>k__BackingField;
} MyStruct;
```

as generated by OleView. I can see it contains the same `k__BackingField` as in the warning - but its not clear what this means.

Answer (score 5):

You are using auto-properties:

```
public string StringA { get; set; }
```

The compiler auto-generates a backing field for each of them. This is exactly what

```
MyNamespace.MyStruct.k__BackingField
```

is referring to.

---

You are getting the warning because exposing a private field *could* be unintended or *could* lead to security issues. It is up to the developer to verify if that is the case. In your specific example, there would be no breach of encapsulation so it's fine to ignore the warning or suppress it. See also the official documentation on this from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1413-avoid-non-public-fields-in-com-visible-value-types?view=vs-2019):

> **When to suppress warnings**
>
> It is safe to suppress a warning from this rule if public exposure of the field is acceptable.

Comment: But why does it issue the warning? What problem does it indicate?

Comment: @DaveInCaz: Consider a class `BankAccount` that has a private field `accountNumber`, and you then export that. COM interop clients can now read a field which the author of the class might have intended to be private *because it is a secret*. The warning is telling you that you need to be aware of this scenario and give it some thought. In your case you have a private field that only exists because a public getter/setter is on top of it, so there is no issue. Really this is a flaw in the warning generation, because it could be smart enough to notice that there is a public getter/setter pair.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks, I kinda felt that this was TLBEXP being too aggresive in its warnings, or lacking nuance to see that this (probably common) case is not a problem. Your last comment seems to back that up.